# Cannot display all rows of same id - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

H, previously i messed around with my scripts on pagination. Then my entire script went crazy. Now, i removed all the scripts relating to pagination, and all of a sudden, now I cannot display all rows of same id. For example. for id 99, i have 9 rows of same id in sql. But it only displays 5 rows. Please help Thanks.

```
  $query="SELECT ua.* FROM useradvert ua INNER JOIN users u ON  ua.id =u.id
     WHERE ua.id='".$id."'";



$stmt = $conn->prepare($query); 
$stmt->execute();
$res2 = $stmt->get_result(); 
$row2 = $res2->fetch_array();


$_SESSION['name2'] = $row2['name2'];
$_SESSION['color2'] = $row2['color2'];
$_SESSION['hobby2'] = $row2['hobby2'];
$_SESSION['radiobtn'] = $row2['radiobtn'];
$_SESSION['kupon'] = $row2['kupon'];
$_SESSION['image'] = $row2['image'];
$_SESSION['image2'] = $row2['image2'];
```

Continue below..on same page

```
while ($row2 = $res2->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

echo "<li>".$_SESSION['name2'] = $row2['name2']."</li>";
    echo "<li>".$_SESSION['color2'] = $row2['color2']."</li>";
    echo "<li>".$_SESSION['hobby2'] = $row2['hobby2']."</li>";
    echo "<li>".$_SESSION['radiobtn'] = $row2['radiobtn']."</li>";
    echo "<li>".$_SESSION['kupon'] = $row2['kupon']."</li>";
    echo  "<li>".$_SESSION['image'] = $row2['image']."</li>";
    echo "<li>".$_SESSION['image2'] = $row2['image2']."</li>";}
```

Comment: I sense something wrong in the while section.. because it is not looping over and over ....it only loops until 5 rows.. anyone out there can give a helping hand?..is there anything in the while section??while ($row2 = $res2->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))..based on my limited knowledge.. it looks fine and suppose to loop over and over until no rows found of same id. (i think so)

Comment: you may join these table by left join, because inner join get related only

Comment: hi @Gouda Elalfy..tq.. I ran my above query in sql (phpmyadmin).. when I change id to e.g 99. it displays all rows of same id.. the only problem is it doesn't display all rows of same id on PHP..i change to left join. still same problem..

Comment: try to remove this code: $row2 = $res2->fetch_array();


$_SESSION['name2'] = $row2['name2'];
$_SESSION['color2'] = $row2['color2'];
$_SESSION['hobby2'] = $row2['hobby2'];
$_SESSION['radiobtn'] = $row2['radiobtn'];
$_SESSION['kupon'] = $row2['kupon'];
$_SESSION['image'] = $row2['image'];
$_SESSION['image2'] = $row2['image2'];

Comment: @Gouda Elalfy ... still same.. no changes on the result.. is my "WHILE" correct btw?i need second opinion

Comment: @Gouda Elalfy...sorry forgive me.. due to my lack of sleep.. i accidently change something else instead of what u suggested.. i followed ur suggestion exactly..to remove the $rows etc.. now it works like a charm.. thank u sooooo much.. please past your answers in the answer section so i can click to accept your answer.. forgive me for my clumsiness..i didn't sleep since lst night..

Comment: I apologise.. my bad..silly me...tq @Gouda Elalfy

Answer (score 1):

you should remove this code, to loop correctly with fetch_array() function:

```
$row2 = $res2->fetch_array(); 
$_SESSION['name2'] = $row2['name2']; 
$_SESSION['color2'] = $row2['color2']; 
$_SESSION['hobby2'] = $row2['hobby2'];
$_SESSION['radiobtn'] = $row2['radiobtn']; 
$_SESSION['kupon'] = $row2['kupon']; 
$_SESSION['image'] = $row2['image']; 
$_SESSION['image2'] = $row2['image2'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your sql query might be causing the problem, try removing the Double quotes

> $query="SELECT ua.* FROM useradvert ua INNER JOIN users u ON ua.id
>   =u.id WHERE ua.id='".$id."'";

TO

> $query="SELECT ua.* FROM useradvert ua INNER JOIN users u ON ua.id
>   =u.id WHERE ua.id='.$id.'";

Comment: tq @Alex Moura..I tried ur suggestion. now i cannot display anything at all....i appreciate your help btw. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry mate! I can't see anything else wrong with the code. Maybe someone will give it a bash